# Can the type of head be a->a?

Tags: haskell

The excerpt below from [Gentle Intro to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html) implies that head's type can be seen as a->a. Is it me who does not understand something or is this a typo?

Probably its just me but then how can head's type be a->a ?

> An expression's or function's principal type is the least general type
>   that, intuitively, "contains all instances of the expression". For
>   example, the principal type of head is [a]->a; [b]->a, a->a, or even a
>   are correct types, but too general, whereas something like
>   [Integer]->Integer is too specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a typo, I believe they meant

```
head :: b -> a
```

since `b` is just a random type variable which would unify with `[a]`.

So in order of increasing specificity,

```
head :: [a] -> a
head :: foo -> a
head :: a
```

Comment: Reasonable, plausible. I'd go with this.

Comment: `a->a` is not only identity functions. `f=f.f` has type `a->a` too.

Comment: addthree x = x + 3 would be also of type a->a, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Perhaps jozefg meant principal type. Meaning that if the principal type is a->a then that can be only the identity function.

Comment: @SassaNF `undefined` too. But that's of little interest. Whenever someone uses words like "proof", they tend to ignore the "ugly" parts of Haskell, such as non-termination and `seq` ;-)

Comment: @jhegedus I believe I did, I've removed that portion of the answer since it's largely orthogonal to the point and not worth clarifying :)